# Openshift Pipeline can not find user

Tags: openshift, openshift-pipelines

I have below error in Openshift Pipeline - tekton pipeline controller

```
Failed to list *v1alpha1.Run: runs.tekton.dev is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:openshift-pipelines:tekton-pipelines-controller" cannot list resource "runs" in API group "tekton.dev" at the cluster scope
```

But I can not see such role (system:serviceaccount:openshift-pipelines:tekton-pipelines-controller). In Role tekton-pipelines-controller all needed rights are added.

Where I can find this user?

Answer (score 0):

> But I can not see such role (system:serviceaccount:openshift-pipelines:tekton-pipelines-controller). In Role tekton-pipelines-controller all needed rights are added.

system:serviceaccount:openshift-pipelines:tekton-pipelines-controller is a ServiceAccount. Granting privileges to ServiceAccounts, you would use RoleBindings (namespace-scoped) or ClusterRoleBindings (cluster-scoped).

tekton-pipelines-controller is a Role. In no way this can be used delegating privileges at cluster scope.

Your error mentions missing privileges at ClusterScope.

> Where I can find this user?

Given its name: this is the tekton-pipelines-controller ServiceAccount, within the openshift-pipelines Namespace.

---

Obviously something's very wrong here. Operators managed by OpenShift's OLM should kinda-work out of the box. If you're struggling with such privileges here: this would indicate your tekton installation is broken. At which point, it may be easier to uninstall then re-install that operator.

Comment: Yes, you were right, after reinstallation all went fine. Thank you.